# Export database to json in a specific format

Tags: php, json

When Exporting database to json I get it in this form:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "siteId": "1",
        "siteUrl": "localhost",
        "identity": "mobie",
        "lastIp": "127.0.0.1",
        "lastLogin": "2018-05-17",
        "loginCountry": "GB",
    }
]
```

Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xamppp\htdocs\auth\mysql.php on line 81

To all of the $user variables.

My database structure is shown as above in the first json output.

Code

```
public function db2json($query){
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $data=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $output = [];

        foreach ( $data as $result )    {  // Change this to loop over the data
            $user = [];
            $user["id"] = $result["id"];
            $user["siteId"] = $result["siteId"];
            $user["lastIp"] = $result["lastIp"];
            $user["lastLogin"] = $result["lastLogin"];
            $user["loginCountry"] = $result["loginCountry"];

            $output[$result["siteUrl"]][$result["identity"]] = $user;
        }

        echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
   }
```

Comment: Yes, but you will have to write your code differently to do that. And you dont show us any code, so it is rather difficult to help you

Comment: I'm just using simple json_decode with the results of the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had to build up some test data, but this will just mean that you change the `foreach()` to loop over your database result instead.  Rather than just assigning the result straight to the output, this just creates the various arrays as you want them in the output...

```
$output = [];

foreach ( $data as $result )    {  // Change this to loop over the data
    $user = [];
    $user["id"] = $result["id"];
    $user["siteId"] = $result["siteId"];
    $user["lastIp"] = $result["lastIp"];
    $user["lastLogin"] = $result["lastLogin"];
    $user["loginCountry"] = $result["loginCountry"];

    $output[$result["siteUrl"]][$result["identity"]] = $user;
}

echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

With my test data, this outputs...

```
{
    "localhost": {
        "mobie": {
            "id": "1",
            "siteId": "1",
            "lastIp": "127.0.0.1",
            "lastLogin": "2018-05-17",
            "loginCountry": "GB"
        },
        "user2": {
            "id": "1",
            "siteId": "1",
            "lastIp": "127.0.0.1",
            "lastLogin": "2018-05-17",
            "loginCountry": "GB"
        }
    },
    "othersite": {
        "user1": {
            "id": "1",
            "siteId": "1",
            "lastIp": "127.0.0.1",
            "lastLogin": "2018-05-17",
            "loginCountry": "GB"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it seemed so simple but I've never done json so i''d have no clue, anyway, I'm getting the error Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in C:\xamppp\htdocs\auth\mysql.php on line 75 anyideas?

Comment: If you could add the complete code to your question I may be able to help.

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: Nevermind ,grabbed the query incorrectly, fixed it :) thanks!

Comment: OK, no problems, glad to be able to help.